# design where divs appear side by side, and stacked when not enough space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not a designer nor very good at the CSS thing, but I am certain boostrap has the power to help me with this (especially across browsers).  Essentially I want to be able to create the following situations

```
DIV-1           DIV-2
DIV-3           DIV-4
DIV-5           DIV-6
```

when there is enough space to two columns of divs (each div will have a fixed width).  When there in't enough space to align them stacked in a single column:

```
DIV-1           
DIV-2
DIV-3           
DIV-4
DIV-5           
DIV-6
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you using bootstrap 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for BS3 you'll want to use this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Column 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Column 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Column 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can change the `6` up to `12` but the total of the `col-md-` must add up to `12`

As the available screen width changes, the columns will adjust to match (`6` being `width:50%`)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

Enable responsiveness

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Add the container with the row and span (bootstrap spans a total of 12 so the number of spans needs to add up to 12

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">Column 1</div>
    <div class="span6">Column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should work is the responsive layout is enabled.

A full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
   body {
    padding-top: 60px;
   }


  </style>

 </head>
 <body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">Column 1</div>
    <div class="span6">Column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

  <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

You can find more information here:
[Bootstrap - Getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html)

Comment: I see you linked to the BS2 docs. This is not valid code for BS3, by the way.

Comment: what would be the BS 3.0 approach?

Comment: This is for the BS2 as Eonasdan rightly said above. Question didn't mention the version of BS, sorry.

Comment: easy enough to convert -looks to be working with their cheat sheet  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your template for the [response design](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) defaults. This will allow your divs to scale with the viewport width.

You are giving your divs fixed width when you really need to use a fluid layout and the `span-*` tags to space out your divs, otherwise it won't have the desired effect.